# "Object required" error when using COUNTIFS in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

**I've got the following line of code**

```
 Worksheets("Pie_Chart").Range(countif_location) = WorksheetFuntion.CountIfs(Range(range_search_countif), failure_to_compare, Range(range_date), ">=" & CDbl(CDate(start_date)), Range(range_date), "<=" & CDbl(CDate(end_date)))
```

**and these are the values of my variables.**

```
countif_location = "D42"

range_search_countif = "Z2:Z39"

range_date = "E2:E39"

start_date = "21/02/2022"

end_date = "28/02/2022"
```

I don't know why but when I try to run this I get the following error "Run-time error '424'; Object required"

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction` not `WorksheetFuntion`

Comment: @Rory thanks! I'm an idiot.

Comment: Note that with `CDate(start_date)` you will Excel let guess what date your string is. Excel cannot know if it is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` so use `DateSerial(2022, 02, 21)` instead to create a real numeric date! If you only have a string then use `a = Split(start_date, "/")` and `DateSerial(a(2), a(1), a(0))`. So you don't let Excel guess. Make sure you decide if your string is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` and not Excel!

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks! I'll definitely try this

Comment: @Pᴇʜ do you know what the default is in Excel? dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: @Sam That's the problem. **There is no default** it uses whatever your system is set to. So default is whatever your Windows is localized to (by default) and if someone changed that like me who is using the [only](https://xkcd.com/1179/) reliable [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, you can't even count on that. So never let Excel convert a `String` into date. Always make sure you split the string into parts and you define which part is day, month and year, to rebuild it as numeric date using `DateSerial`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thank you. I've been working in a few macros this week where I manage dates and it is a pain to do so I will definitely have this in mind for those macros.

Comment: Dates are pretty easy to handle if you have them as numeric value, whenever they get converted into strings, that's where problems start. So always try to have them as numeric value in the cells and use `.NumberFormat` to format them as date (so they look like whatever you prefer). As long as the cell value is numeric you can calculate with those dates and everything is fine.